# XSLT-2.0: code working for all items except the first one

Tags: xslt, foreach, xslt-2.0, xsl-variable

Consider the following XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lieferungen>
    <artikel id="3526">
        <name>apfel</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="true">8.97</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Krause</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="7866">
        <name>Kirschen</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="false">10.45</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Helbig</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="3526">
        <name>apfel</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="true">12.67</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Liebig</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="7866">
        <name>Kirschen</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="false">17.67</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Krause</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="3526">
        <name>apfel</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="true">9.54</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Mertes</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="7866">
        <name>Kirschen</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="false">16.45</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Hoeller</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="7868">
        <name>Kohl</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="false">3.20</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Hoeller</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="7869">
        <name>Kirschen</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="false">12.45</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Richard</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="3245">
        <name>Bananen</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="false">15.67</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Hoeller</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="6745">
        <name>Kohl</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="false">3.10</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Reinhardt</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="7789">
        <name>Ananas</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="true">8.60</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Richard</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="3225">
        <name>Bananen</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="false">15.67</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Schmidt</lieferant>
    </artikel>
</lieferungen>
```

As you can see, there are inconsistencies w.r.t the IDs of the "artikel" (= articles).

For example:

Article "apfel" has id="3526" in line 2 but id="3526" in line 12.

With the following XSLT code I want to display all these inconsistencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="lieferungen">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Inkonsistenzen</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Inkonsistenzen</h1>
                <hr/>               
                <xsl:for-each-group select="artikel" group-by="name">
                    <p>
                        <xsl:text> Name: </xsl:text> 
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>

                        <xsl:variable name="this_id" select="@id"/>

                        <xsl:text> Lieferant=  </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="lieferant"/>

                        <xsl:text> , ID=</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$this_id"/>


                        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                            <xsl:if test="$this_id != @id"> 
                                <xsl:text> Lieferant=  </xsl:text>
                                <xsl:value-of select="lieferant"/>

                                <xsl:text>; ID=</xsl:text>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>

                                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </p>

                </xsl:for-each-group>

            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output I get is the following:

```
Name: apfel Lieferant= Fa. Krause , ID=3526
Name: Kirschen Lieferant= Fa. Helbig , ID=7866 Lieferant= Fa. Richard; ID=7869
Name: Kohl Lieferant= Fa. Hoeller , ID=7868 Lieferant= Fa. Reinhardt; ID=6745
Name: Bananen Lieferant= Fa. Hoeller , ID=3245 Lieferant= Fa. Schmidt; ID=3225
Name: Ananas Lieferant= Fa. Richard , ID=7789
```

As you can see, my xslt-code worked perfectly fine for all articles except for one: apfel (which is the first article listed in the xml-file). This seems totally crazy to me. Why does my xslt-code work for all items except the first one?

Comment: "*Article "apfel" has id="3526" in line 2 but id="3526" in line 12.*" The difference being ... ?

Comment: The arikel nodes with name apfel have the same id's, i.e., 3526. your code  compares the id's of he arikel nodes with same names and hence is working as expected.

Comment: I can confirm both previous comments: the XSLT is working as "expected" (maybe not by you, but...).

Comment: SORRY ..... you are right ... I somehow kept seeing different ids but it is the same ... probably I have been sitting in front of the computer for too long!!!
Thank you all for your help!